# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element at Object.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to run the code but i'm getting *Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.* error. I'm testing the below code

**In Slider.jsx**

```
      render() {
        const { activeSlide, prevSlide, sliderReady } = this.state;
        return (
          <div className={classNames('slider', { 's--ready': sliderReady })}>
            <p className="slider__top-heading">Travelers</p>
            <div className="slider__slides">
              {this.props.slides.map((slide, index) => (
                <div
                  className={classNames('slider__slide', { 's--active': activeSlide === index, 's--prev': prevSlide === index  })}
                  key={slide.city}
                  >
                  <div className="slider__slide-content">
                    <h3 className="slider__slide-subheading">{slide.country || slide.city}</h3>
                    <h2 className="slider__slide-heading">
                      {slide.city.split('').map(l => <span>{l}</span>)}
                    </h2>
                    <p className="slider__slide-readmore">read more</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="slider__slide-parts">
                    {[...Array(this.IMAGE_PARTS).fill()].map((x, i) => (
                      <div className="slider__slide-part" key={i}>
                        <div className="slider__slide-part-inner" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.img})` }} />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="slider__control" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(-1)} />
            <div className="slider__control slider__control--right" onClick={() => this.changeSlides(1)} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const slides = [
      {
        city: 'Paris',
        country: 'France',
        img: require('assets/images/img4.jpg'),
      },
     {
        city: 'Banglore',
        country: 'India',
        img: require('assets/images/img5.jpg'),
      },

    ];

    ReactDOM.render(<Slider slides={slides} />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

**In INDEX.js**

```
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App>
        <Router history={hist}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Components} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </App>
    , document.getElementById("root"));
```

**In index.html**

```
    <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```

**In App.js**

```
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Router history={hist}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Components} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    <Slider/>
        </div>  
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

**Error showing:**
    Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
        at invariant (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:225988:19)
        at Object.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:248161:40)
        at Module../src/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3170:50)
        at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:782:30)
        at Object.0 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:3715:18)
        at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:782:30)
        at checkDeferredModules (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46:23)
        at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33:19)

Comment: Why do you have a `ReactDOM.render()` line in your `Slider.jsx`? Also, in App.js you are rendering the main structure, there's no need to put any more than `<App />` in your index.js `ReactDOM.render()` call.

Comment: If I remove ReactDOM.render() from Slider.jsx I'm getting this error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. @Chris G

Comment: In your App.js, use `<Slider slides={slides} />` and move the declaration (`const slides`) inside the file. Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ptolemy-sjlml

Comment: In App.js I've other file called components, which has other components to display so in App.js I'm using components.! I need to use this Slider.jsx component along with those components. @Chris G